# What will be the final polynomial for this recurrence relation?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

Given a recurrence relation: 
$$ax_n-bx_{n-1}-2x=(xa-b)x_{n-1}-ax_{n-2}-2x$$ where $a=x^3(x^2-3)-(x^2-1) \text{ and } b=x(x^2-3).$

What will be the final polynomial?

Comment: 'Final polynomial' is rather vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given recurrence reduces to:

$$
\require{cancel}
a\,x_n\cancel{-b\,x_{n-1}}-\bcancel{2\,x} = a\,x\,x_{n-1}\cancel{-b\,x_{n-1}}-ax_{n-2}-\bcancel{\,2x} \iff a\,x_n = a\,x\,x_{n-1}-ax_{n-2}
$$

If $a=0$ then the above is satisfied by any sequence $x_n\,$ otherwise it further reduces to:

$$
x_n = x\,x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}
$$

The latter is a linear homogeneous recurrence, which does not depend on $a,b\,$. Given some initial conditions $x_{0,1}$ it can be solved using the standard methods, though the solution will (generally) not be a polynomial in $x\,$.

Answer (score 1):

So x is a constant? Just get the difference eqiation,

$$
a x_{n-1}  - b x_{n-2} -2x=0
$$

Subtract it from the one you have to get rid of the constant. Can you take it fromhere?